# How to Find & Select NON English Characters in Hive Table

Tags: hadoop, hive, regexp-like, rlike

How to find Table records which are having Non-English (Spanish/Chinese/Japanese/..etc) characters in multiple columns. I tried below query but I couldn't able to find exact result. Can someone please help me on this.

Query:

```
SELECT 
      tbl1.id                 AS id
    , tbl1.first_name         AS first_name
    , tbl1.second_name        AS second_name
FROM emp_table tbl1                                                         
WHERE ((tbl1.first_name RLIKE '[^a-zA-Z\\d\\s:]') OR (tbl1.second_name RLIKE '[^a-zA-Z\\d\\s:]')) 
;
```

Eg:

```
id  first_name  second_name
1   尚            爱华
2   Shané        Olum�
3   Abc           Xyz
4   PQR           RST
```

Expected Output would be ID :

```
id  first_name  second_name
1   尚            爱华
2   Shané        Olum�
```

Comment: What error are you getting at the moment?

Comment: @BenWatson Watson, I'm not getting any error. I'm getting records (id=3 & 4) records with above query but I should get id=1&2. Can you please help on this ??

Comment: You're getting the opposite of what you want? Stick a `NOT` in then.